# Convert Python List to CSV

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, retinanet

I want to train my own dataset using retinanet. 
The Retinanet github page says that I need to convert my dataset's annotations to csv format. Retinanet csv format:

```
path/to/image.jpg,x1,y1,x2,y2,class_name
```

I've converted my own dataset's annotations into a python list. List example:

```
['/home/atakan/VOC2007/JPEGImages/bookstore_video0_1.jpg,1382,553,1420,602,Pedestrian',...]
```

Convert list to csv code :

```
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter =' ',quotechar =',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for i in liste:
        writer.writerows([[i]])
```

But I can't get csv output in retinanet format. Where am I doing wrong?Thanks...

Comment: For one, your delimiter should be `delimiter = ","`

Comment: Are you aware about module [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) ?

Comment: @AlexYu - Atakan is using the CSV module in the csv code.

Comment: Atakan, is each item in the list you have created in the csv? If so, what are the headers? Are they `path,x1,y1,x2,y2,class_name` like your first line?

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to show what the output should look like for that data. You currently just have a list with one item that is a string already in CSV format. i.e. explain what is needed for `retinanet`.